# Is displaying/printing a "Hello World" message in Java/Python same as in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, devops

I want to print "Hello World" in k8s, but I am confused how to do it.

I am new to Kubernetes.

How do I display "Hello World" by creating an image/container when accessed via a web server on a port.

Do I need to mandatorily install npm, or others in my dockerfile ?
Or is there any way to simply use bash commands to echo "hello world" and display that as output in a Web server.

Please guide.

Comment: If you didn't have Kubernetes, and you wanted to display "hello world" on a Web page, what's the simplest thing you could do?  (Yes, you probably do need a custom image with some kind of HTTP service.)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response. I want to know that if in a Dockerfile I include an entry point or a CMD and display a message, is it possible to get the message output in Kubernetes? I would not use any Nodejs or Nginx or Reddis Application to display this message, but only a simple CMD or ENTRYPOINT to do so? Is it possible? Example dockerfile code: CMD echo "Hello World" or ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/bash" , "l" , "c" ,'echo Hello World" ] ??

Comment: That's not really a use case for Kubernetes.  You could run a Job with that container and look at its logs when it finishes, but it'd be an unusual setup.  (What benefits are you hoping to get from running this process in Kubernetes?)

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes is an orchestrator, it is not a language such as JavaScript, you can create a javascript app, and then create a docker image containing the said app which you can then run in a kubernetes cluster.

I must say though, that your question makes me wonder if you have any experience in how containers or orchestrators work, which makes me think I should recommend you to read up a bit more and play around a bit more with it before trying to run it on a live environment.

If you don't want to listen to the above, you will basically need the following:

- A deployment, with a pod running your container with the app inside.
- A service, exposing the deployment to the cluster.
- An ingress(route), exposing your service to the outside net.

There are other ways to do it, but k8s is not an "easy thing" to work with, it requires quite a bit of research and testing to allow you to know what you are doing before it is useful.

Comment: Hi Jite, thanks for your reply. I will try to learn more on k8s.

Comment: I want to know that if in a Dockerfile I include an entry point or a CMD and display a message, is it possible to get the message output in Kubernetes? I would not use any Nodejs or Nginx or Reddis Application to display this message, but only a simple CMD or ENTRYPOINT to do so? Is it possible? Example dockerfile code: CMD echo "Hello World" or ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/bash" , "l" , "c" ,'echo Hello World" ] ??

Comment: Sorta, the output will be in the container logs, so might not be very much to look at, but it _is possible_ :) Each container runs just as it does in docker locally on your computer, just with a more high level orchestrator which takes care of the scheduling and such :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with learning to use Docker. Containers is mostly "a way" to run processes in an isolated environment, so to do anything in a container, you need to do that with a process, e.g. bash or a custom application.

You can run both **commands** and **services** in a Docker container.

When deploying apps to Kubernetes, it is **services**, e.g. a web server listening on a port. But you can also run **commands** on Kubernetes by using [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)

Here is a "hello world" Job using bash:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: centos:7
        command:
         - "bin/bash"
         - "-c"
         - "echo hello world"
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for your response. I want to know that if in a Dockerfile I include an entry point or a CMD and display a message, is it possible to get the message output in Kubernetes? I would not use any Nodejs or Nginx or Reddis Application to display this message, but only a simple CMD or ENTRYPOINT to do so? Is it possible? Example dockerfile code: CMD echo "Hello World" or ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/bash" , "l" , "c" ,'echo Hello World" ] ??

Comment: Hi Jonas,Also a question on your sample hello World code, where do I get the centos:7 image, is it the same as any OS base image like rhel or others? Can they be just kept in a repo and given the repo details in your Job yaml file and when we create this Job, we would get HelloWorld as result in k8s?